# Dividing polynomial, multiple divisors and remainders

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Problem:
If we divide $P(x)$ by $x-1$, then the remainder is $1$.
If we divide $P(x)$ by $x^2+1$, then the remainder is $2+x$.
What is the remainder when we divide $P(x)$ by $(x-1)(x^2+1)$?

My attempt:
I know $P(1)=1$ from first condition, I tried to see if I can extract more information from second condition, but I am clueless.
Any ideas?

Comment: If you know complex numbers you know that $P(i) =2+i$ and $P(-i) =2-i$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: Use the division algorithm: $A(x)=B(x)Q(x)+R(x)$, $\deg(R)<\deg(B)$

**Another Hint**: if you have a good background about modular arithmetic, try to do it the same way as the Chinese Remainder Theorem problems.

**Solution**:
So  let's try
$$P(x)=(x-1)Q_1(x)+1 \tag{1}$$
$$P(x)=(x^2+1)Q_2(x)+x+2 \tag{2}$$
Now let's work on this a little bit. Put $x=1$ in $(2)$ knowing that $P(1)=1$ from $(1)$, we get
$$1+2Q_2(1)+3 \iff Q_2(1)=-1$$

Note that $$Q_2(x)=(x-1)Q_4(x)+a \implies a=Q_2(1)=-1$$
$$\implies P(x)=(x^2+1)((x-1)Q_4(x)-1)+x+2$$
$$=(x^2+1)(x-1)Q_4(x)+(-x^2+x+1)$$
And we're done!

---

---

**Another solution** (but with the same algorithm) is using complex numbers:
$$P(x)=(x-1)Q_1(x)+1 \tag{$A(x)$}$$
$$P(x)=(x^2+1)Q_2(x)+x+2 \tag{$B(x)$}$$
$$B(i) \implies P(i)=2+i$$
$$A(i) \implies 2+i=(i-1)Q_1(i)+1 \iff Q_1(i)=\frac{i+1}{i-1}=-i$$
and we note that 
$$Q_1(x)=(x^2+1)Q_3(x)+ax+b$$
$$x\mapsto i\implies -i=ai+b \implies a=-1,b=0$$
$$\implies Q_1(x)=(x^2+1)Q_3(x)-x$$
$$\implies P(x)=(x-1)((x^2+1)Q_3(x)-x)+1 = (x-1)(x^2+1)Q_3(x)+(-x^2+x+1)$$

---

---

**Another Solution**: Treat it as chinese remainder theorem but in polynomials, I'll solve it the same way I solve the normal chinese remainder theorem:
$$P(x) \equiv1 \pmod{x-1} \implies P(x)=Q(x)(x-1)+1$$
$$Q(x)(x-1)+1\equiv x+2 \pmod{x^2+1}$$
$$\implies Q(x)(x-1) \equiv x+1 \equiv x+1-(x^2+1)\equiv x(1-x) \pmod{x^2+1}$$
$$\implies Q(x)\equiv -x \pmod{x^2+1} \implies Q(x)=H(x)(x^2+1)-x$$
$$\implies P(x)=(x-1)(H(x)(x^2+1)-x)+1=(x-1)(x^2+1)H(x)+(-x^2+x+1)$$
and that's it. We're done.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, $R(x)$, has to have degree at most $2$, because we're dividing by a cubic polynomial.

Furthermore, $$R(x)\equiv1\pmod{x-1} \tag{1}$$ and $$R(x)\equiv 2+x\pmod{x^2+1}$$

If we write $$R(x)=2+x+k(x^2+1),$$ then we know that $k$ has to be constant. But we also know from $(1)$ and the fact that $x \equiv1 \pmod{x-1}$ that $$R(x) =2+x+k(x^2+1)\equiv3+2k \equiv1\pmod{x-1}$$
 so that means $k=-1$ and the final solutions is $R(x)=-x^2+x+1.$

Answer (score 0):

$$P(x)=Q_1(x)(x-1)+1=Q_2(x)(x^2+1)+(x+2).$$

Then by the extended Euclidean algorithm, we solve

$$Q_1(x)(x-1)-Q_2(x)(x^2+1)=x+1.$$

The solution is
$$-(x^2+x+1)(x-1)+x(x^2+1)x+1$$

and

$$P(x)=2-x^3.$$